# How to calculate a file count in tcsh?

Tags: tcsh

I want to add a new file based on how many similar files are there already in tcsh. Here is my code.

```
set aNum = (`ls -ld a* | wc -l` + 1)
echo "aNum is $aNum"
```

Since I already have a file a*, I expect aNum be set to 2, but it is actually set to "1+1". How do I ask the script to calculate the value instead of the string?

Comment: `@ aNum` works; `set aNum` implies strings, `@ aNum` evaluates/assigns

Comment: Thank you. It works. How do I make this the answer to my question?